# Unable to Instantiate Activity Component Info error

Tags: android, android-activity, components

In my app I got Unable to instantiate activity component info.I know this question has been answered lot of time in this forum. But I cant find the proper solution to resolve the same error.I scartch my head for last two days.Here is my code,

```
package com.example.sms;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
Button signup=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signup);
Button signin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signin);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.patient_login);
    signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intentSignUP=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignupActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentSignUP);

}
    });
signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intentSignUP=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignupActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentSignUP);

}
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

This is my manifest file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.sms"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.sms.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.sms.SignupActivity">
     </activity>

</application>
```

Can anyone help me to find where I did the mistake.Any help could greatly thankful.

Comment: post your logcat error

Comment: @Uday: are you using any jar inside your application

Comment: sorry Sankar Ganesh:)What is meant by jar here...

Comment: can you please post the error which is shown in Logcat,so that i can help to reslove your force close error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is you always map your xml UI components inside the onCreate method of your activity as i shown below

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    Button signup = null;
    Button signin = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.patient_login);
    signup=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signup);
    signin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signin);
    // your code
    }
```

**Please refer  the Activity life cycle diagram , onCreate method only the UI components which you have used in .xml are mapped to your activity and in OnDestory method the components which ever you used are freed from Memory, similar to malloc and free in C.
Note: The onCreate method is the entry point of your android application,like main method is the entry point of java/c/c++ program.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

move

```
Button signup=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signup);
Button signin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signin);
```

lines inside `onCreate` method of `LoginActivity` Activity after `setContentView` because currently you are trying to access views without setting layout for current Activity.do it as:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
Button signup,signin;  //<<Declare Button here

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.patient_login);
    // initialize buttons here
    signup=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signup);
    signin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signin);
   /// your code here....

}
```

Comment: @Prosper K:)yeah its helped to me.But it often shows force close dialog.

Answer (score 0):

This is because yout are initializing your button outside onCreate.
 Only declare it globally and do findViewById inside onCreate after your setContentView

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
Button signup;
Button signin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.patient_login);
    signup=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signup);
    signin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signin);
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So your code declaration after setContentView method and this code put and solve your problem,

```
    Button signup=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signup);
    Button signin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signin);

    signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intentSignUP=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignupActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentSignUP);

    }
    });
    signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intentSignUP=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignupActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentSignUP);

    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

All UI elements must be initialized in the overridden activity methods

Like in onCreate, onResume ... Here you are initializing in the main class itself

**your code**

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
Button signup=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signup);
Button signin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signin);
```

**Actual code**

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    Button signup;
    Button signin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       signin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signin);
       signup=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signup);
    }
}
```